# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zeep'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, zeep

I have created a virtual environment on which I ran the following command to install Zeep (I am on macOS Big Sur):

```
pip3 install zeep
```

To verify if I have correctly installed it I ran:

```
pip3 freeze
```

And I can see in the list :

```
zeep==4.0.0
```

However, when I run my script using `flask run` I get the following error:

[image]

I have flask installed and activated my virtualenv:
[image]

What I don't understand is that when I go directly on python from the command line it does import zeep :

[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does **flask** appear in the output of `pip freeze` as well besides **zeep**? Just confirm once

Comment: Yes it does ...

Comment: whats the output for `pip3 --version`?

Comment: It is pip 20.2.3

Comment: doesn't it show the path of pip? Can you post that as well? If it doesn't, can you verify output of `pip3 show zeep`?

Comment: Yes it shows the path which is /.../cpas/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

Comment: When I do pip3 show zeep I get the version of zeep as well as the name, the summary, home-page and so on

Comment: What is the value of **Location** when you run `pip3 show zeep`? Does that match the pip3 path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234894/discussion-between-sandeep-gusain-and-colla).

Comment: The location of pip3 show zeep is /.../cpas/lib/python3.8/site-packages and the location of pip3 is /.../cpas/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip

Answer (score 0):

Two things come to my mind with this problem.

- Make sure the venv is activated

> source /venv/bin/activate

- Make sure flask is installed after activating the venv.

> pip install Flask

Comment: Thank you for the response. I updated my question to show you I have both activated my venv and flask installed.

Answer (score 0):

You are running in an Anaconda/Conda virtual environment, this can be seen from your command prompt. Conda is a package management platform like, but separate to, Pip.

When you install a package with Pip it is not available in an Anaconda virtual environment.

Also you need to take note of where you are actually installing packages to when you run `pip`. If you run pip outside of a virtual environment then it is going to install packages into your system Python which is not a good thing.

> I have flask installed and activated my virtualenv:

How are you activating the virtual environment? Your third screenshot shows the Anaconda installation of Python.